# Regular Expression with a boolean outcome

Tags: regex

I am new to Regex, Please can you help me with the below?

I want a Regex that spits out 1 if a match is found and 0 if not found? I am using this inside a workflow tool so it has to be one expression not a multi-line .Net syntax.

Is this even possible?

**Example:**

```
If Value1 = abcd, then Regex output: 1

If Value2 = NULL or EMPTY, then Regex Output: 0

If Value3 = 15/03/2016, then Regex Output: 1
```

Thanks in Advance,
D

Comment: for regex you should have a role or pattern. so if value exist, is your role, correct?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of this requirement served by simple `if-else`?

Comment: Regex only deals with string extraction, it doesn't evaluate anything nor does it convert  string results to any other types. There are language specific methods for that. Use if regex.ismatch(string) then return 1 else return 0.

Comment: it's not possible. regex is for *matching*; regex doesn't "do" anything

Comment: Thank you, I decided to handle it in an SQL Query.